# Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $a \in G$ with $B_X(a,r)\cap \delta G = \emptyset$. Then $B_X(a,r) \subseteq G$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I came up with the following and wanted to be sure if my proof is correct:

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $a \in G$ with $B_X(a,r)\cap \delta G = \emptyset$. ($\delta G$ is the boundary of $G$). Then $B_X(a,r) \subseteq G$.

**Proof**: Suppose not. Then we can pick $z \in B_X(a,r)$ with $z \notin G$. The line segment $[a,z]$ is contained in $B_X(a,r)$, since balls are convex.

Put $f(t)= a(1-t) + zt, t \in [0,1]$

Put $t_0 := \inf\{t : f(t) \notin G\}$, which exists because $f(1) = z \notin G$ and note that $f(t_0) \notin G$ by the continuity of $f$. Also note that $t_0 \neq 0$, since $a=f(0) \in G$. Thus, we can take a sequence $0 \leq t_n, n \geq 0$ such that $t_n \nearrow t_0$ (strictly) and by the continuity of $f$ we have $f(t_n) \to f(t_0)$. However, $f(t_n) \in G$ for all $n$ and hence $f(t_0)$ is in the closure of $G$. But this means that $f(t_0) \in \overline{G} \cap G^c = \overline{G} \cap \overline{G^c}= \delta G$, because $G$ is open. This contradicts the hypothesis $B_X(a,r) \cap \delta G=\emptyset$.

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you define $B_X(a,r)$. Do you set $X=\mathbb{C}$ here and do you mean a ball with radius $r$ and center point $a$?

Comment: And what do you mean by a "line segment $[a,z]$". If $a,z\in\mathbb{C}$ this notation does not make so much sense, since you can not order complex numbers.

Comment: Yes to both questions. And $[a,z]$ is shorthand notation for the line segment connecting $a$ and $z$ in the complex plane.

Comment: For the line segment, he means $f([0,1])$, ie., the segment with $a$ and $z$ as extremes.

Comment: The argument seems correct to me.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd just cut it short and say that balls in $\Bbb C$ are connected and, by the trichotomy $X=A^\circ \sqcup \delta A\sqcup (A^c)^\circ$, $(B(a,r)\cap G)\sqcup (B(a,r)\cap (G^c)^\circ )$ is an open cover of $B(a,r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B_X(a,r) \cap \partial G= \emptyset$, $B_X(a,r)$ cannot intersect $G^\complement$ or the ball would be disconnected (by the disjoint cover $G$ and $\Bbb C\setminus \overline{G}$, intersected by $B_X(a,r)$.

This argument works for any connected neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: Another case where the metric obscures things! Topology gives super quick proofs.